# outlook calendar event background sync in outlook add-ins

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In the Outlook calendar i want to trigger Outlook creates event functionality in my outlook add-ins when I open the Outlook calendar, Is there are any handlers available for this use case?
I want to trigger create the event functionality in the outlook add-ins using the rest-API when I open the Outlook calendar.

Any handler is available for this, the outlook calendar open ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to trigger an event when you open the calendar? Is my understanding correct? In case, if you are looking for this, the outlook add-in framework does not support this event. This is the documentation for supported events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

Answer (score 1):

Outlook web add-ins are working under the context of current item only. You can't handle folder's change events like you could in case of COM add-ins. The event-based activation mechanism recently introduced is described in the [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) article. This feature enables your add-in to run tasks based on certain events, particularly for operations that apply to every item (not folder). You can also integrate with the task pane and UI-less functionality.